# Magento 2: Get all the option label (per store scope) from attribute code

Tags: magento2.3, product-attribute, store-view, attribute-options

Currently my code is

```
use Magento\Eav\Model\Attribute;
use Magento\Eav\Model\AttributeRepository;
use Magento\Framework\Api\SearchCriteriaBuilder;


 $searchCriteria = $this->searchCriteriaBuilder->create();

 /** @var Attribute[] $attributesList */
 $attributesList = $this->attributeRepository
                  ->getList('catalog_product', $searchCriteria)
                  ->getItems();

  foreach ($attributesList as $attribute) { 
      // For example; attribute code: sample (see below image)
      print_r($attribute->getStoreLabels()) //(array) Working: getting all the labels available per store scope
      foreach($attribute->getOptions() as $option){
           print_r($option->getLabel()) //(string) Working but getting the admin store scope
           print_r($option->getStoreLabels()) // NOT WORKING: gives only empty value; 
      }
  }
```

I want to get all the labels from all store view as it can be different. Many thanks for the help!

Example of one product attribute is below:

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this way - in your foreach, before calling any method to retrieve the option labels, set the store ID of interest `$attribute->setStoreId($storeId)` and then try retrieving the option labels as you already tried. If this works properly, consider moving the code to a dedicated model and inside it loop through all the stores you need.

Comment: Thanks! for the response, I am trying to set the storeId but the method is not available. Then I found another article that say's it is using a magic method (setData()), thus storeId worked for me just like what you said. Do you also know how can I update these attribute option per store scope? Thanks

Comment: yes, the method is a magic method, there is no concrete definition of it. please consider marking this answer as solution and open another question regarding the option updates. thanks